# XML Schema for choice between element and #PCDATA

Tags: xsd

I have a preexisting XML document type that has an element that can have two content types: some elements, or just text. Modeling this as mixed content is overkill, and JAXB's XJC creates a very ugly binding as a result.

```
<bars><bar .../><bar .../></bars>
```

versus

```
<bars>Just a bunch of #PCDATA</bars>
```

xs:choice seems structured only for complex types (not simple types like xs:string). Is there a way to express this choice, between elements or text, using XML schema? In DTD this would be something like

```
<!ELEMENT bars (#PCDATA | bar*)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language you want to define (either a sequence of character or a sequence of `bar` elements, but not a mixture) cannot be defined in XSD 1.0 (or in XML DTDs, either; your DTD notation would make sense but is not legal in XML DTDs).

In XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion to ensure that if any `bar` elements are present as children, no text nodes occur (or only text nodes that contain only whitespace).

A simple way to achieve roughly the same effect is to say that the `bars` element contains either a sequence of `bar` elements or a single `stringvalue` element (call it whatever you like), where the `stringvalue` element contains -- as its name suggests -- just a string of characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and the confirmation that I'm not missing some aspect of XML Schema that would allow this type of document to be modeled better than as mixed content.